# How do I pass a javascript variable from one html page to another without Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

If beeing looking around stackoverflow for a long time now but I can't find an answer that is detailed enough for me to understand. (Sorry for my bad English.) I want to save a javascript variable to the input in a search bar and than pass it to another page. The pages are modeled after Amazon. The first page is called Verkoopwedstrijd2num1.html and the second one is called Verkoopwedstrijd2num2.html. Can you maybe put the code that you come up with directly into my code cause I already found solutions but I don't know how to implement them.

Page 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Verkoopwedstrijd2.css">
<link href="Verkoopwedstrijd2num2.html">
</head>

  <body>
    <div class="bar">
        <a class="TEXT" href="Verkoopwedstrijd2num1.html">Amazon</a>
        <div class="search-container">
              <input type="text" name="Text"  placeholder="Search" id="SearchBar">
              <button class="Button">Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="ExtraSpace1">
        <button class="left">&lt</button>
        <button class="right">&gt</button>
    </div>
    <div class="ExtraSpace2">
        <div class="ExtraSpaceItem1">
        Willekeurige text om uit te proberen <br> hoe dit werkt. Loet
        </div>
        <div class="ExtraSpaceItem2">

        </div>


        <div class="ExtraSpaceItem3">

        </div>
    </div>
      <script>
          var SearchBarInput = document.getElementById("SearchBar").value;

          window.onload = function() {
           var getInput = prompt(SearchBarInput);
          localStorage.setItem("storageName",getInput);
}

          function myFunction () {
          var x = document.createElement("p");
          var t = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
          x.appendChild(t);
          document.body.appendChild(x);

          var element = document.getElementById("div1");
          element.appendChild(x);
          }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Page 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Verkoopwedstrijd2.css">
<link href="Verkoopwedstrijd2num1.html">
</head>

  <body>
    <div class="bar">
        <a class="TEXT" href="Verkoopwedstrijd2num1.html">Amazon</a>
        <div class="search-container">
            <input type="text"   placeholder="Search">
              <button class="Button">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div1"><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button></div>
<div>
      <ul id="myUL">
  <li><a class="hide">Alah Akbar</a></li>
  <li><a class="hide">A is for</a></li>

  <li><a class="hide">Big chungus</a></li>
  <li><a class="hide">Bitch lasagna</a></li>

  <li><a class="hide">Chungus</a></li>
  <li><a class="hide">Car sans</a></li>
  <li><a class="hide">Comic sans</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<script>

window.onload = alert(localStorage.getItem("storageName"));

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("p");
  var t = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(x);

  var element = document.getElementById("div1");
  element.appendChild(x);
}


/*function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
} */
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are both documents on the same server / origin

Comment: you're showing `localStorage`, which has nothing to do with jQuery, so: just... keep using that? As long as the pages are on the same domain, localStorage values set by any page on that domain can be read by any other page on that domain.